# When and where did the myth about solar eclipse affecting pregnant women start?

Tags: astronomy

Evidence for presence of myth -

1. https://www.lifecell.in/mom-and-baby/pregnancy/care/eclipse-harmful-pregnant-women-myth-or-truth

> In India, eclipse is linked to many dos and don’ts for everybody as it
>   is believed to be a bad omen. Pregnant women are advised not to come
>   outside, eat or cook during a solar and lunar eclipse because people
>   believe that it may have side effects on the growing baby

2. http://amp.usatoday.com/story/579196001/

> Aztecs believed a lunar eclipse was a result of a bite being taken out
>   of the moon. This idea translated into the Mexican superstition that
>   if a pregnant woman viewed an eclipse, a bite would be taken out of
>   her unborn child's face. Hindu text credits the eclipse to the head of
>   the demon Rahu, who ate the moon or sun.

3. https://www.babycenter.in/x1011503/is-an-eclipse-harmful-during-pregnancy

> There are some superstitions that an eclipse can cause deformities
>   such as a cleft lipor unsightly birthmarks

**Questions** - Which was the first known civilization in which this myth was present?

What were the reasons behind this myth i.e. (why did they think so)?

Comment: The quoted passages seem to suggest that there are at least two different myths and possibly other unrelated supersititions. Is there one in particular of interest?

Comment: @SteveBird can we club them under a single myth as "eclipse badly affects  foetus". the specifics of the damage may differ depending on civilization/time period.

Answer (score 2):

Cursory googling suggests the superstitions date back to [Hindu beliefs](http://www.hinduism.co.za/eclipse.htm) and [Aztec times](http://www.stltoday.com/lifestyles/parenting/pregnant-superstitions-abound-about-the-solar-eclipse-for-expecting-moms/article_8c9b5679-e959-5753-abe1-e8e940116126.html), so tracing the superstitions' exact origins and their precise explanations may prove very hard or impossible.

That said, their explanations [probably are](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/11/131101-solar-eclipse-myth-legend-space-science/) related to this:

> "If you do a worldwide survey of eclipse lore, the theme that constantly appears, with few exceptions, is it's always a disruption of the established order," said E. C. Krupp, director of the Griffith Observatory in Los Angeles, California. That's true of both solar and lunar eclipses.

Comment: thanks, i got an answer from an old question on Hinduism.SE (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20393/290) Would be interesting if people here could expand upon that.

Comment: @user13107 the old question seems to suggest that the myth is that a risk occurs if there's an eclipse at the time of conception rather than generally during pregnancy.

Comment: @SteveBird correct! answerer is saying that that particular logic `might have been extrapolated` to entire duration of pregnancy. It would be helpful if something definitive can be said further.